# What is the best practice to pass spaces to Lua from expl3?

Tags: luatex, expl3

In LuaTeX, using the `\directlua` primitive (within a standard LaTeX2e setup)

```
\directlua{tex.print("Hello World!")}
```

will produce "Hello World!" to the output PDF.

On the other hand, in expl3 code

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\lua_now:e { tex.print("Hello~World!") }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

left "HelloWorld!" (no space between `Hello` and `World!`) to the input stream.

What is the best practice to pass spaces to Lua interpreter from expl3 code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, we recommend that Lua chunks are defined separately from `expl3` (or indeed standard LaTeX) code, so they can simply be loaded using `require()`. Where you do want a short piece of Lua 'inside' `expl3`, using `~` is the correct action. However, when you use `tex.print` or similar to return tokens to TeX, LuaTeX tokenizes them using *the current catcode regime*. As such, your space gets ignored. However, there is an optional argument to `tex.print()` which takes a category code table number: this can be used to apply any catcode setup one likes.

At present, we are finalising category code table support for `expl3`. The 'Lua side' is perhaps not quite right just yet, but it is workable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3cctab}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\lua_now:e { tex.print(\int_use:N \c_document_cctab, "Hello~World!") }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\end{document}
```

(Eventually, `l3cctab` will be part of the `expl3` core.)

Category code tables are supported by LaTeX nowadays *via* `ltluatex`: you could avoid loading `l3cctab` entirely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\lua_now:e { tex.print(\number\catcodetable@latex, "Hello~World!") }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\end{document}
```

Comment: we really should fix that `\number` requirement

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, that did bother me too, hence the 'we are working on it' part: probably we should have a Lua name for the information, which we can create in parallel with the `\count` (so we don't have to point to the `tex.count` table)

Comment: yes or allow \e@allocate to use \def rather than \chardef to define the allocated integer so they are expandable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That was my other thought too (also for `expl3` version). I see the point, but I suspect longer-term this should have a 'proper' Lua-side interface

Answer (score 10):

As Joseph said, the default `tex.print` will tokenize by the catcode current at that point so rather than letting `~` making a space then printing with a normal catcode regime, you can print with the `expl3` catcode regime which means that you nneed to print a `~` so need to avoid the `~` being tokenised as a space as it's passed to Lua:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\lua_now:e { tex.print("Hello \c_tilde_str World!") }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\end{document}
```